# Loading file to Hbase using PIG

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, apache-pig

File Content :

```
one,1
two,2
three,3
```

file location : hdfs:/hbasetest.txt

Table in Hbase :

```
create 'mydata', 'mycf'
```

PIG Script :

```
A = LOAD '/hbasetest.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (strdata:chararray, intdata:long);
STORE A INTO 'hbase://mydata'
        USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage(
              'mycf:intdata');
```

And i m getting following error :

ON CONSOLE

```
2012-03-13 16:26:22,170 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.ScriptState - Pig features used in the script: UNKNOWN
2012-03-13 16:26:22,170 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - pig.usenewlogicalplan is set to true. New logical plan will be used.
2012-03-13 16:26:22,204 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/zookeeper/KeeperException
```

In Log File :

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. org/apache/zookeeper/KeeperException

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/KeeperException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.setConf(TableOutputFormat.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage.getOutputFormat(HBaseStorage.java:389)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.InputOutputFileValidator$InputOutputFileVisitor.visit(InputOutputFileValidator.java:87)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOStore.accept(LOStore.java:76)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:64)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.depthFirst(DepthFirstWalker.java:66)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.DepthFirstWalker.walk(DepthFirstWalker.java:53)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:50)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.rules.InputOutputFileValidator.validate(InputOutputFileValidator.java:52)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.compile(HExecutionEngine.java:292)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.compilePp(PigServer.java:1365)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1207)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1201)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.access$100(PigServer.java:129)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.execute(PigServer.java:1528)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1575)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:534)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:871)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:388)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:168)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:144)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:76)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:455)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 25 more
============================================
```

If i use DUMP command, it shows file content on grunt.
How to rectify this issue??

Comment: You might get more help if you mark answers for some of your previous questions first

Comment: not familiar with hdfs/pig, but that looks like a classpath problem. Do you have the zookeeper jar's in your classpath ?

Comment: ya, i added all the required jars in classpath

Answer (score 2):

Add `hbase-*.jar` and `zookeeper-3.3.2.ja`r to the `PIG_HOME` and `PIG_HOME/lib..` also set `PIG_CLASSPATH=/HADOOP_HOME/conf`, `HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/HADOOP_HOME/conf` and `HADOOP_HOME` to your hadoop installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines in in your .bashrc

```
export PIG_CLASSPATH=$PIG_HOME/pig-x.x.x-withouthadoop.jar:$HBASE_HOME/hbase-x.x.x.jar:$HBASE_HOME/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/*:$PIG_CLASSPATH
```